# Die Lines Drawing of boxes Adobe illustrator cc script

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

[image]http://swsharings.blogspot.com.tr how do I do this for the described here FEFCO 0201 code box ?

I tried so hard but I couldn't

The .jsx script can be downloaded at the following link instances.

In addition these examples might need people. Are Sorry for my English.

Comment: I understand it may be a language barrier but I have no idea what your question is.

Comment: Thanks Cai, http://swsharings.blogspot.com.tr is
I downloaded a sample of the written language on-site scripting Indonesia I translate into English with Google Translator.
An example I'm working on a more detailed example.

Comment: Its like postscript in jsx. Not bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (yeah i should refactor it but i cant be bothered, did it for fun):

```
#target illustrator

// Copyright joojaa 2016
// License: Buy somebody you do not know 
// a beer or other similar culturally 
// appropriate refreshment.

(function(){
var win = new Window('dialog');
var height = txtgroup(win, 'Height', '30 mm');
var width = txtgroup(win, 'Width', '10 mm');
var length = txtgroup(win, 'Length', '40 mm');

var grp = win.add('group');
var ok = grp.add('button {text: "OK"}');
grp.add('button {text: "Cancel"}');

var doDraw = function(){
    draw();
    win.close(0);
    }
ok.onClick = doDraw;

win.show();

function txtgroup(win, name ,txt) {
    var grp = win.add('group');
    grp.add('statictext {text: "'+name+': "}');
    var item = grp.add('edittext {characters: 12, active: true}');
    item.text = txt;
    return item;
}

// almost from scriptUI for dummies
function convert_units(n, to) {
  var unitConversions = {
    'pt': 1.0000000000,
    'p': 12.0000000000,
    'mm': 2.8346456692,
    'in': 72.00000000,
    'ag': 5.1428571428,
    'cm': 28.3464566929,
    'c': 12.7878751998,
    'tr': 3.0112500000
  }
  var obj = fix_measurement(n);
  var temp = (obj.amount * unitConversions[obj.unit]) / unitConversions[to];
  return temp
}

// almost from scriptUI for dummies
function fix_measurement(n) {
  n = n.replace(/ /g, ' '); // Delete all spaces
  n = n.replace(/^([pc])/, '0$1'); // Change p3 to 0p3
  // Infixed 'p' and 'c' to decimal suffixes: 3p6 > 3.5 p
  n = n.replace(/(\d+)([pc])([.\d]+)$/, function() {
    return Number(arguments[1]) + Number(arguments[3] / 12) + arguments[2]
  });
  // Split on unit
  var temp = n.split(/(ag|cm|mm|c|pt|p|in)$/);
  return {
    amount: Number(temp[0]),
    unit: temp.length === 1 ? doc_units() : temp[1]
  };
}








function draw(){

var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
grp = myDoc.groupItems.add();
grp.name = 'dieline';
function line(){

    var l = grp.pathItems.add();
    l.stroked = true;
    l.filled = false;
    return l;
}

var w = convert_units(width.text, 'pt');
var l = convert_units(length.text, 'pt');
var h = convert_units(height.text, 'pt');    

var mm =2.8346456692
var o = [10*mm, -10*mm];
var p = o;

//flap

line().setEntirePath([
                     p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ], 
                     p=[p[0] - (w/8 + 4*mm), p[1] - (w/16 + 2*mm)],
                     p=[p[0], p[1] - (h + 6*mm) + 2*(w/16 +2*mm)],
                     [o[0], p[1] - (w/16 +2*mm)]
                     ]                     
                     );

// horizontal lines 
var p = o;
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(h + 6*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);

var p=[o[0] + (w + 4*mm), o[1]];
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(h + 6*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);

var p=[p[0] + (l + 5*mm), o[1]];
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(h + 6*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);

var p=[p[0] + (w + 4*mm), o[1]];
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(h + 6*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);

var p=[p[0] + (l + 5*mm), o[1]];
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(h + 6*mm) ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm) ]]);

// then vertical
var p = o;
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (w + 4*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (l + 5*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (w + 4*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (l + 5*mm), p[1] ]]);

var p=[o[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm)];
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (w + 4*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (l + 5*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (w + 4*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (l + 5*mm), p[1] ]]);

var p=[o[0], p[1] -(h + 6*mm)];
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (w + 4*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (l + 5*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (w + 4*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (l + 5*mm), p[1] ]]);

var p=[o[0], p[1] -(w/2 + 3*mm)];
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (w + 4*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (l + 5*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (w + 4*mm), p[1] ]]);
line().setEntirePath([ p, p=[ p[0] + (l + 5*mm), p[1] ]]);

return grp;
}

})();
```

Comment: The script works very well.
How do I convert a rectangular shape in all fields. 

That's my only problem now.

Comment: @ensio in the very beginning there is 3 line lf vars for height width and length there you see and set the default values.

Comment: @ensio delete the lives with var w = unitconvert(xxx) But wouldnt it be easier just leave that in and assume default units is mm and then let the user type whatever unit if it is not?

Comment: @ensio Look I did it for fun, if i must debug/change stuff for you its like work. For work you should hire me. I have a better unit input system that can accept defaults but its too many lines to share across this link but again its for fun. Dont make it feel like work. please.